# the Ukrainian utility, Ukrenergo -- what do they mean by "utility" here?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Ukraine Bids for Attention With Crimea Blackout](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2015-11-23/ukraine-bids-for-attention-with-crimea-blackout?cmpid=yhoo.headline)

Example:

> The "blockade" probably did more damage to Ukrainian companies than to Russian power in Crimea: Stores in the peninsula filled with Russian and Turkish goods, albeit at higher prices. Yet the activists who maintain the checkpoints had a more potent weapon. On Nov. 13, the Ukrainian **utility**, Ukrenergo, announced that the country no longer needed Russian electricity because some new nuclear power capacity had just come online. Just a week later, the first two transmission towers in the Kherson region were blown up.

What do they exactly mean by *utility* here?

Comment: A *utility company* ([энергетическая или коммунальная компания](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=utility)). See "[public utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_utility)" and "[electric utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_utility)"

Comment: @CopperKettle: I suspect that many native speakers who weren't brought up on [Monopoly](http://www.faqoverflow.com/boardgames/8485.html) wouldn't automatically recognise the unqualified term as used in OP's example. I also find it intriguing that the *American* versions pictured in my link put the word in "scare quotes". I don't recall the British ones doing that, but it *is* evidence that the usage is/was recognised as "potentially unfamiliar, even to a native speaker". So I think this Q shouldn't have been closed, and I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I never voted to close it in the first place.

Comment: @CopperKettle: I can see that from the display. What I *can't* see is whether you're one of the two other users who voted alongside me to reopen. Which is entirely your decision, of course, but if you didn't already it's possible you (or anyone else reading my comment) might be persuaded to do so after considering the implications of those scare quotes on a playing card that's clearly aimed at native speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm usually pretty sympathetic to reopening these types of questions, but this is pretty straightforward to look up. Googling "utility definition" takes you straight to it. The first item on the Wikipedia disambiguation page for "utility" is "an organization that maintains the infrastructure for a public service, or the services themselves". I'm gonna say leave this one closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Utility](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utility) means:

> a company that provides electricity, water, etc.

[Merriam-Webster]

Mostly state-owned company in each country provided basic public utilities such as electrical power, water, heat, etc. in the old days as it is one of the biggest capital-intensive industries that require a tremendous amount of investment at the beginning.

*The national electricity (power) company of Ukraine* is called "[NPC Ukrenergo](http://www.bloomberg.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=39034461)" and "NPC" stands for *National Power Company*.

Comment: It's interesting that the dictionary I consulted didn't have that meaning listed. So, I just wanted to make sure I got things right with this word.

Comment: @CookieMonster I am not 100% sure, but "utility" for a utility company is more broadly used in American English. I would appreciate a comment from BrE speakers.

Comment: Of course, it's kind of obvious that the word probably means "utility company", but you never know. Sometimes things that look simple on the surface turn out to mean something slightly different when you take an extra effort and do a little more digging up.

Comment: @Rathony: My suspicion (as pointed out in [an earlier comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73945/the-ukrainian-utility-ukrenergo-what-do-they-mean-by-utility-here#comment141916_73945)) is that the British version of Monopoly doesn't have "utilities" in scare quotes on the Water Works & Electric Company cards. Which might be taken as evidence that some people (at Hasbro, at least) think that the usage is more common in BrE than AmE.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is strange that Oxford Online Dictionary doesn't have a definition for a company that provides electricity, water, etc.

Comment: It's there in [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/220771?redirectedFrom=utility#eid) under defn 3 c: *public utility: see public utility n. at public adj. and n. Special uses 2. **Also simply utility. Hence, a company providing such a service or supply**. In pl. also shares in such a company. chiefly N. Amer.* I take it that means *Cautious investors tend to favour utilities* is more likely in AmE than BrE (spelling notwithstanding! :)